# Mikrotik simple queue, Limiting range of IPs

Tags: networking, mikrotik

I'm using a ***Mikrtotik*** *RB201UiAS* to manage my network. 
To avoid creating simple queues for every IP i have created queues for ranges of IPs.

[image: Screenshot of simple queues]

- Target:            172.16.2.0/25
- Dst:               ether1
- Target Upload:     5M
- Target Download:   5M

The question is: Using this configuration

- **each IP** (From 1 to 127) will have a limit of 5M Tx/Rx

or

- **all IPs** (From 1 to 127) will have a limit of 5M Tx/Rx

Current configuration:

```
# oct/21/2015 15:25:55 by RouterOS 6.23
# software id = U3SW-9LU3
#
/queue simple
    add dst=ether1 max-limit=5M/10M name=Klasat target=172.16.2.0/25
    add dst=ether1 max-limit=5M/10M name=Administrata target=172.16.2.128/26
    add dst=ether1 max-limit=1M/1M name=DVR target=172.16.2.192/27
    add dst=ether1 name=Sallat target=172.16.2.224/28 add dst=ether1 name=Unlimited target=172.16.2.240/28
```

Comment: Please post your configuration. `/queue export`

Comment: `# oct/21/2015 15:25:55 by RouterOS 6.23`
`# software id = U3SW-9LU3`
`#`
`/queue simple`
`add dst=ether1 max-limit=5M/10M name=Klasat target=172.16.2.0/25`
`add dst=ether1 max-limit=5M/10M name=Administrata`
`target=172.16.2.128/26`
`add dst=ether1 max-limit=1M/1M name=DVR target=172.16.2.192/27`
`add dst=ether1 name=Sallat target=172.16.2.224/28`
`add dst=ether1 name=Unlimited target=172.16.2.240/28`

Comment: It seems that you probably use the `default-small` Queue Type which means that the limit is applied to all IPs. You need to use PCQ type to apply the limits on per-IP basis. Check my answer for more details.

Comment: Make sure you disable the fasttrack firewall entry, this got me, It comes set default on new routers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are using [PCQ queue type](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Queues_-_PCQ), then the limits are applied to all IPs in the defined range.

With [PCQ (Per Connection Queue)](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Queues_-_PCQ) you can apply the desired limits on each IP based on the criteria you define on the PCQ (dst/src address, dst/src port, or any combination of those).

From MikroTik official [documentation](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Queues_-_PCQ):

> PCQ was introduced to optimize massive QoS systems, where most of the
>   queues are exactly the same for different sub-streams. For example a
>   sub-stream can be download or upload for one particular client (IP) or
>   connection to server.
>
> PCQ algorithm is very simple - at first it uses selected classifiers
>   to distinguish one sub-stream from another, then applies individual
>   FIFO queue size and limitation on every sub-stream, then groups all
>   sub-streams together and applies global queue size and limitation.
>
> PCQ parameters:
>
> ```
> pcq-classifier (dst-address | dst-port | src-address | src-port; default: "")  : selection of sub-stream identifiers
> pcq-rate (number) : maximal available data rate of each sub-steam
> pcq-limit (number) : queue size of single sub-stream (in KB)
> pcq-total-limit (number) : maximum amount of queued data in all sub-streams (in KB)
> ```
>
> So instead of having 100 queues with 1000kbps limitation for download we can have one PCQ queue with 100 sub-streams

There is also an example available at [MikroTik Wiki](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Queues_-_PCQ_Examples)

Wiki excerpt:

> There are two ways how to make this: using mangle and queue trees, or,
>   using simple queues.
>
> 1. Mark all packets with packet-marks upload/download: (lets constider that ether1-LAN is public interface to the Internet and ether2-LAN is
>      local interface where clients are connected
>
>    ```
>    /ip firewall mangle add chain=prerouting action=mark-packet in-interface=ether1-LAN new-packet-mark=client_upload
>    /ip firewall mangle add chain=prerouting action=mark-packet in-interface=ether2-WAN new-packet-mark=client_download
>    ```
> 2. Setup two PCQ queue types - one for download and one for upload. dst-address is classifier for user's download traffic, src-address for
>      upload traffic:
>
>    ```
>    /queue type add name="PCQ_download" kind=pcq pcq-rate=64000 pcq-classifier=dst-address  
>    /queue type add name="PCQ_upload" kind=pcq pcq-rate=32000 pcq-classifier=src-address
>    ```
> 3. Finally, two queue rules are required, one for download and one for upload:
>
>    ```
>    /queue tree add parent=global-in queue=PCQ_download packet-mark=client_download
>    /queue tree add parent=global-out queue=PCQ_upload packet-mark=client_upload
>    ```
>
> If you don't like using mangle and queue trees, you can skip step 1,
>   do step 2, and step 3 would be to create one simple queue as shown
>   here:
>
> ```
> /queue simple add target-addresses=192.168.0.0/24 queue=PCQ_upload/PCQ_download
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Cha0s :) 
I am not using firewall mangle so I just changed the simple queues from 
`add dst=ether1 max-limit=5M/10M name=Klasat target=172.16.2.0/25` to 
`add dst=ether1 max-limit=5M/10M name=Klasat queue=pcq-upload-default/pcq-download-default target=172.16.2.0/25`.

I can not test it now since everyone has gone from the company, will test it tomorrow morning.

Comment: I get `input does not match any value of parent` when I attempt to execute step 3. Replacing `global-in` and `global-out` with `global` seems to fix it, however, I cannot get any limiting to work with the full version (using mangling) OR the simple queue option (as noted on Denis' answer). Using speedtest I still get 30Mbit/sec even though I am limiting to 2M. I am using RouterOS 6.32.4.

Comment: My issue was that I had a `fasttrack` firewall filter rule that came installed by default on my router. After disabling that, these rules work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Cha0s](https://serverfault.com/users/168407/cha0s)'s answer I managed to create the fair limiting without creating hundreds of simple queues.

> A note for other viewers trying to do the same thing.

Be careful after adding Queue Types to **configure** the Download/Upload Limit at **Queue Type Rate** and **remove** ( make unlimited ) the Target Upload & Target Download from **Simple Queue**

My Example:

---

```
 /queue type
      add kind=pcq name=pcq-download-Klasat pcq-classifier=dst-address pcq-rate=2M
      add kind=pcq name=pcq-upload-Klasat pcq-classifier=src-address pcq-rate=2M

 /queue simple
      add dst=ether1 name=Klasat queue=pcq-upload-Klasat/pcq-download-Klasat 
      target=172.16.2.0/25 total-queue=pcq-download-Klasat
```

Comment: This doesn't limit traffic for me at all; what could I be doing wrong? Do you have anything else set up? Also I am not sure this qualifies as a separate answer currently.

Comment: My issue was that I had a `fasttrack` firewall filter rule that came installed by default on my router. After disabling that, these rules work fine.